# How Navigation Drawer will take Full Screen width?

Tags: android, navigation

Dear friends i [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnUuX.jpg)want to make a navigation Drawer with  full screen width, when i click on Navigation_View Button a side bar is opening with full screen height but almost 90% width of whole screen but i want to expand it on the full screen.. 
is it possible ? if yes then kindly let me know how it will be possible.?

[Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nUey.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754305/full-width-navigation-drawer) answer.
Briefly - set negative layout margin to drawer.

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        layout="@layout/drawer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"/>
```